# Asp.Net Webhooks with Stripe

Tags: c#, asp.net, stripe-payments

NET Webhooks has an option of using it with Stripe out of the box. I haven't been able to find any documentation on this, and the few examples show the git hub example.

When I select Stripe it asks me for a key, I'm wondering why it needs the key and which key does it need (the publishable key or the secret key) ?

I'm trying to do a WebHook for the Charge.Suceeded event, any sample code would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The webhook handler needs your [secret API key](https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys) in order to [verify the events](https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/guide#verifying-events):

- https://github.com/aspnet/WebHooks/blob/fccb722c14950fd72c48d5d7eede44ea4f521a7a/src/Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.Stripe/WebHooks/StripeWebHookReceiver.cs#L109-L110